# C# LINQ To Sql Default Object Instantiation Over Optimization?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

It seems the LINQ to SQL compiler is over optimizing default class values for classes that have other classes inside them.

Here is some sample code that illustrates the problem:

```
void Main()
{
    testInitialValueFromDB();
}

void testDefault()
{
    using(DataContext db = new DataContext()) //in my actual code its GEMSDBDataContext where it got created from a .dbml file
    {
        var result = db.GEMSUsers.Take(10).Select(x=> new AllInfo {
            info = new InitialInfo {
                Test1 = x.username.Length
            },
            info2 = new SetAfterInfo {
                Test2 = ""
            }
        }).ToList();

        result[0].info2.Test2 = "Setting afterwards";
    }
        //from now on all the values in result say Setting afterwards

}

void testInitialValueFromDB()
{
    using(DataContext db = new DataContext()) //in my actual code its GEMSDBDataContext where it got created from a .dbml file
    {
        var result = db.GEMSUsers.Take(10).Select(x=> new AllInfo {
            info = new InitialInfo {
                Test1 = x.username.Length
            },
            info2 = new SetAfterInfo {
                Test2 = x.rowguid.ToString()
            }
        }).ToList();


       result[0].info2.Test2 = "Setting afterwards";
    }
    //This actually works and only the first item is changed
}

void testGuid()
{
    using(DataContext db = new DataContext()) //in my actual code its GEMSDBDataContext where it got created from a .dbml file
    {
        var result = db.GEMSUsers.Take(10).Select(x=> new AllInfo {
            info = new InitialInfo {
                Test1 = x.username.Length
            },
            info2 = new SetAfterInfo {
                Test2 = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            }
        }).ToList();

        //I would expect Test2 to be a new guid everytime but it's always the same, like the class got instantiated only once.
        result[0].info2.Test2 = "Setting afterwards";
        //again this changes for all the elements in the list
    }
}

public class AllInfo
{
    public InitialInfo info {get; set;}
    public SetAfterInfo info2 {get; set;}
}

public class InitialInfo
{
    public int Test1 {get; set;}
}

public class SetAfterInfo
{
    public string Test2 {get; set;}
}
```

Now if you call testDefault() or testGuid() what seems to happen is SetAfterInfo only gets initialized only once, and if I change any element's Test2 property it gets updated in every item from the list.

I ran into this error because I had to run a Query, but I had to set a property to a value in a way that couldn't be represented in SQL so I was doing it after the ToList() call in code.

The only method that works is if Test2 gets initialized from the database, in that case the output is what is expected.

I am just curious if this is a legitimate bug in the LINQ to SQL compiler.

Some more info:

.NET Framework 4.5
SQL Server 2012

Comment: At face value I'd say that looks highly implausible -- but then, it occurs to me that I don't know what `GEMSUsers` is. The optimization you claim to see is not something that would be done by the C# compiler -- instead, it'd be done by the LINQ IQueryable implementation which in your case might be buggy. It is at least theoretically possible for an implementation to look at the Expression, see that the object literal expression doesn't reference the argument or the closure and optimize it to a cached "constant".

Comment: Could you fix the [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QWtFRd) so we can run the code?

Comment: Ahh sorry I did this as a quick test in LINQPad. GEMSUsers is in a DataContext. I'll update the sample code to make it more clear. So unless fiddle has some sort of live database I can't make the code run on fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug in the sense of a deviation from the spec since the behavior of this query is not documented. Many things are not documented with L2S (and EF).

But it is a bug in the sense that the team would likely agree that this should be changed.

Unfortunately, the L2S team no longer exists. The product is abandoned. Don't expect a fix.

As a workaround introduce an artificial dependency:

```
        info2 = new SetAfterInfo {
            Test2 = someStringColumn.Substring(0, 0) //empty string
        }
```

L2S will no longer think that the initializer for `info2` is constant. You can use  any other artificial dependency in this spirit. For example you could assign a column to a dummy property.

Comment: Yeah that is basically what I ended up doing. It was driving me mad because when the bug was reported I looked through the code multiple times with multiple people and it didn't seem like there should be a problem. 

It's too bad that Linq to SQL is dead. I quite enjoyed the framework, thankfully this bug is on a legacy project at our company now.

Comment: EF was catching up for like 5 years after L2S was made dead. EF still does not allow me to switch over a 100 KLOC app that I run because it lacks some LINQ query features. So sad. L2S was developed by the C# team and they really knew what they were doing.